# How to delay a loop in "for" keyword in Android?

Tags: android

I'm trying to show about 400 items data by adding a view on custom layout.

but when do this, screen is freezing for a while ( 3 ~ 4 second).

I think this cause is that main thread is busy for processing 400 items, thus can't refresh a view.

so I'd like to give a delay in "for" loop for a little second (0.3 ~ 0.5second).

How to delay in "for" loop?

```
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    for (int idx = 0; idx < jArray.length(); idx++) {
        JSONObject jItemObj = jArray.getJSONObject(idx);

        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.task_taxi_11000_item, null);
        TextView tv_TsDateTime = (TextView) v
                .findViewById(R.id.tv_TsDateTime);
        TextView tv_Amt = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tv_Amt);
        TextView tv_AuthNo = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tv_AuthNo);
        TextView tv_SvcCdNm = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tv_SvcCdNm);
        TextView tv_AppCoNm = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tv_AppCoNm);

        if (jItemObj.has("TR_TM")) {
            tv_TsDateTime.setText(Convert.ComDate.strTime
                    .formatTimeDelimiter(jItemObj.getString("TR_TM")));
        }


        if (jItemObj.has("APP_NO"))
            tv_AuthNo.setText(jItemObj.getString("APP_NO"));
        if (jItemObj.has("AMT"))
            tv_Amt.setText(Convert.strAmount.format(jItemObj
                    .getString("AMT")) + "AMT");
        if (jItemObj.has("SVC_CD_NM"))
            tv_SvcCdNm.setText(jItemObj.getString("SVC_CD_NM"));
        if (jItemObj.has("APP_CO_NM"))
            tv_AppCoNm.setText(jItemObj.getString("APP_CO_NM"));

        mLlList.addView(v); // <== can't refresh layout.    
    }
```

Comment: Please, just read something about RecyclerView and the ViewHolder pattern. Your life will become much easier.

Comment: you can use handler, Timer

Comment: Can you show some example source using handler, timer?

Comment: Why don't you do the parsing in a background thread before hand and prepare an object which can be used directly inside the method?

Comment: ViewHolder will be your savior.

Comment: Thanks every one. I had not known about viewholder until now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read about ViewHolder pattern and see an example here - http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html

What it basically does is it does not load all items together; instead, it loads only the objects required to display on screen.